# How to Calculate the average monthly food expenditure in this excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I need to calculate the average monthly food expenditure in this excel sheet? can anyone help me,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JydHq.png) please? I looked up but found no solutions

Comment: Get the date in a different column and then use Pivot Tables grouping by months. Also read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: So how would you take the average of a column of numbers? Then consider averageif() or even averageifs().

Answer (score 0):

In a new cell type

```
=AVERAGE(
```

And then select the cells to take the average of. Then press enter or tab to finish the formula and you should see the average appear.

Comment: Will this separate the months? Remember the OP wants monthly average.

Comment: No it will provide a singular average; In the image it seems the excel sheet already has monthly food expenditure and OP wishes to find the average of this column.